# Involuntary initial struggle of doing something different

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

> I find people are limited in growth in technology due to them not expanding their skill  despite it not being difficult  so they end up being held back  despite the demand in business and in job marking being in new technology. Technology constantly changes and being valued at corporations is dependent on overcoming ***** steps.
>
> This phenomenom can be described by an analogy. If you slowly move your finger up against a balloon, you feel resistance and feel like it is pushing back. You move your hand further still feeling the resistance until it pops and you can move on. These people are really smart and not lazy. The struggle in the first step of learning something new and different and give up. They need to learn to over the *****.

Words I can think of

> *barrier/friction/glass ceiling/struggle/opposition*

Neither describes the face that the friction is just in the beginning. Learning the new thing isn't really hard but the resistance is merely in it being different and new.

I guess it is similar to waking up early in the morning or exercising. Initially it is very hard but becomes routine it is easy and become easy.

> Two people get given the same task of fishing. One tries to immediately catch  fish with his hands. The other takes his time by making a net. The former could have done the same as it would make fishing so much easier however the friction of doing something different to what his existing methods was, he found to hard .

What do you call (single word or compound word) the *initial friction* of doing something different or the bias of not wanting to do it because it is different/strange/alien even though it is beneficial once that irrational mental block gets passed.

Not a dislike. Almost a *phantom resistance* but that isn't a recognized phrase. Not a *mind block* but a mind bubble but that also isn't a recognized phrase

Comment: Don't try to call them ***** steps. Call them ***steep learning curves***.

Comment: Different isn't steep.   Waking up an hour earlier isn't steep at all.

Comment: _Overcoming inertia_ works.

Comment: Not a dislike. Almost a phantom resistance but that isn't a recognized phrase. Not a mind block but a mind bubble but that also isn't a recognized phrase

Comment: @devc2: I'd say if you think *initial struggle of doing something different* applies, there's almost certainly a "non-trivial learning curve" involved. But if *steep* is a bit steep for you, just call them ***learning curves***.

Comment: Waking up early in the morning is a false analogy. Whether you find it easy to wake up early or not only partially depends on habit—the larger part of it is more or less hard-coded in you. Many people find getting up early exceedingly difficult, and this does not change with routine. After two years in a previous job where I had to get up at 7 every morning, it was still torturously hard for me to do.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet you wanted to wake up early when you went to bed, you just found it hard in the morning, so you weren't resistant to change, your body was.

Comment: So this seems to be a question about the resistance to 'good', or maybe even inevitable,  change.  I'd like to see another question posed as resistance to 'bad' change.  Would both 'limited' individuals be characterized  'resistive to change'.  A SAP implementation comes to mind :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Resistance to change*

See:

*[Ten Reasons People Resist Change](https://hbr.org/2012/09/ten-reasons-people-resist-chang)*

*[Resistance to Change](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/sideways-view/201610/resistance-change)*

Comment: Calling someone resistant to change sound like a personality trait like they themselves are resistant. In the example I'm thinking of their personality is not resistant to change but they try the change out and give up due to the initial mind friction.  Their minds might be resistant to change but this is involuntary resistance only due to initial friction.

Comment: @devc2 Take a look at the [Ten Reasons People Resist Change](https://hbr.org/2012/09/ten-reasons-people-resist-chang) link. Suggested reasons are **Loss of control**, **Excess uncertainty**, **Everything seems different**,**Loss of face**,**Concerns about competence**,**More work**,**Ripple effects**, **Past resentments**, **Sometimes the threat is real**.